# Switch environment in OPAM

Tags: ocaml, opam

Is this possible to have several development environments, which share the same compiler?

Actually, I want to use `4.00.1+short-types` compiler with different set of installed packages, and the possibility to easily switch between these environments. `opam switch` only allows me to switch between compilers if I didn't miss something.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I suppose the solution is to create new switches that are aliases of the one you're interested in, using the `opam switch install <name> --alias-of <switch>` command described in the [Usage](http://opam.ocaml.org/doc/Usage.html#opamswitch) document.

Comment: It seems a separate copy of the compiler is installed (I thought it may be shared somehow). Anyway, this is a solution. Thanks