# How can I switch the opam compiler in an easy way and what is the --set-switch flag?

Tags: ocaml, opam

Consider:

```
$ opam switch set ocaml-variants.4.07.1+flambda_coq-serapi.8.11.0+0.11.1
# Run eval $(opam env --switch=ocaml-variants.4.07.1+flambda_coq-serapi.8.11.0+0.11.1) to update the current shell environment

$ eval $(opam env --switch=ocaml-variants.4.07.1+flambda_coq-serapi.8.11.0+0.11.1)
[NOTE] To make opam select the switch ocaml-variants.4.07.1+flambda_coq-serapi.8.11.0+0.11.1 in the current shell, add --set-switch or set OPAMSWITCH
```

But then it doesn't tell me at all where `--set-switch` should go. Why? Where?

Related:

- *[Switch environment in OPAM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15564542/switch-environment-in-opam)*

Answer (score 1):

It's confusing why it gives you a command, but then the command doesn't work. If you browse the opam man page, it says (*[opam-switch](https://opam.ocaml.org/doc/man/opam-switch.html)*):

> opam switch set sets the default switch globally. The shell hook, when enabled, synchronises the current shell session with this switch, unless the current directory is a local switch, when that local switch is used instead. You can always use eval $(opam env --switch=SWITCH --set-switch) to specify the switch explicitly, which overrides the shell hook.

Then it works if you do:

```
eval $(opam env --switch=ocaml-variants.4.07.1+flambda_coq-serapi.8.11.0+0.11.1 --set-switch)
```

See:

```
$ opam switch
#  switch                                                  compiler                       description
   coq-8.10                                                ocaml-base-compiler.4.07.1     coq-8.10
   default                                                 ocaml.4.14.0                   default
→  ocaml-variants.4.07.1+flambda_coq-serapi.8.11.0+0.11.1  ocaml-variants.4.07.1+flambda  ocaml-variants.4.07.1+flambda_coq-serapi.8.11.0+0.11.1
```

It is really annoying and confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. A new OCaml compiler was released and I wanted to change the one I was using.

You can list the ones available using `$ opam switch list`. I had the default switch that is generated if you follow the installation instructions from the official page (which is named `default`).

Then I created another switch with the 5.1.0 version of the compiler using: `$ opam switch create 5.1.0`. I didn't provide a name for the new switch, just the compiler version I wanted. So the switch name became just the compiler version, i.e., 5.1.0.

Now list the switches available, and select the new one by writing the corresponding name of the switch you want: `$ opam switch set 5.1.0`.

Also, it would be helpful for you to read the docs of the `switch` option. Try it by writing in the terminal `$ opam switch --help`. This is what I did to assign a different switch.

I just started using OCaml, so I can't explain to you about the specific flag you are interested in but hope this helps.

Just keep in mind that probably you will have to install all the necessary packages that you need, even if they are installed in your previous switch. I ignore if this can be done differently.